# Wordpress e-commerce plugin caps total order cost at 999,999,999

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, e-commerce

I have a problem with an ecommerce website. I am using Wordpress, and the ecommerce plugin [Wordpress E-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/).

I do not know much PHP so I do not understand why this is happening.

My problem is that when people place orders that exceed 999,999,999 currency, it cuts off at 999,999,999. For example, If somebody bought 2,400,000,000 worth of items, it would cut off at 999,999,999 for each item.

Does anybody know why this happens? or a workaround to fix it?

From what I see in the PHP files, this is the code used to compile the "Total Price".

```
$total = 0;
$shipping = $row['pnp'];
$total_shipping += $shipping;

$total += ( $row['price'] * $row['quantity']);
```

Comment: This might be a MySQL problem. Look into the database schema and find out of which data type the price is.

Comment: The $row variable suggests that these values are being retrieved from a database. Check the columns they're being retrieved from and see if one of them is defined as int(9). If so, alter the table so that it allows more digits.

Comment: Are you fetching this record from database? If so than its database limit not php.

Comment: It is probably a database constraint, check how the price column is defined. Also I can't resist asking: who buys stuff for BILLIONS from your shop?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6612791/67381) answer for more detail.

Comment: What products are you selling for >`999,999,999¤`? This is not the relevant PHP code which would do that. (Most likely MySQL as the other commentors pointed out). You should rather watch out for rounding errors, which are nigh at that integer range.

Comment: @Vatev well, if they're Japanese then it's only tens of millions in USD (and if they're in São Tomé and Príncipe, only 50k). I'm guessing this is a fictional economy, though.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your quick responses. I found that the type was a "decimal(11,2)". I'm not too sure what I have to change it to, but things have gotten a lot easier. thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: 11,2 means that it contains 11 digits, including 2 after the decimal point. Alter the table so that the number of digits is large enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change the data length in MySQL. By the way, congratulations on finding that limit. You're clearly doing well in online sales!